# rails url as breadcrumb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Feature request for SEO optimized url :- 
(friendly url only replaces id with the name/title),

Current URL Washing Machine is:
//localhost:3000/products?product_category_id=15#WashingMachine
Custom URL for the same page should be: (as per bread-crumbs)
http://localhost:3000/HomeEssentials/Cleaning&Drying/WashingMachine
Where HomeEssentials > Cleaning&Drying > WashingMachine is the bread
crumbs, and it has the parent child menu structure.

This has to happen at every product category, and for ex,
product?product_category_id=35#Football, in terms of breadcrumbs :-
Home > Sports & Leisure > Football.
(leading to a url like -
localhost:3000/Home/Sports&Leisure/Football.)

I have had a look at friendly url gem, and stubs, and changing to_param
in the model , but that effectively replaces the id with the title/name,
or any parameter we set. However it does not replace the entire url, in
the manner as expected.
(the answer probably lies in changing the routes file, (mapping, etc)
but have not received much success in my search so far).
Currently, the request is being generated from the home page, into the -

> products controller and the parameter product category id is being
>   passed.

<%=
link_to subMenuCat_tab.name, products_path(:product_category_id =>
subMenuCat_tab.id) %>

Any suggestion / help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use this gem https://github.com/fnando/breadcrumbs. it's very simple to integrate.You can then add your own css to design.

Comment: @monsur, tried the same. Actually, we already have an implementation of , gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails', alongside I added the new one, gem 'breadcrumbs', '~> 0.1.7'. add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path is a part of existing implementation and it is being used as <%= render_breadcrumbs :tag => :li, :separator => "" %>, in the products index.html.erb page. But, the question is, having is displayed in the url.

Answer (score 0):

What if

in you routes.rb

```
get 'HomeEssentials/:product_category_title/:product_title' to: 'products#show'
```

then in you products_controller.rb

```
def show
   @product = Product.find_by(title: params[:product_title], product_category_id: params[:product_category_title])     
end
```

Comment: i tried the same, but with little success. Request from home page to each of these links looks like - Started GET "/products?product_category_id=15" for ::1 at 2016-09-08 13:38:27 +0530
Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"product_category_id"=>"15"}. The routes file initially had  resources :products,    only: [:index, :show, :create]. Modified to include - 
  get '/HomeEssentials/:product_category_title/:product_title', to: 'products#show' . The show method in the products controller is never invoked although rake routes does have a new route.